# Display how many people have a product in their WooCommerce cart but add a (temporarily) random number to the result

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

Similar to what you see on stores like Etsy, I would like to display the number of people that have a product in their cart.

Via [Show how many people have added a product in their current cart](https://itzmekhokan.wordpress.com/2019/08/06/show-how-many-people-have-added-a-product-in-their-current-cart/), I was able to achieve it.

But my website is still under construction, and when I start it, I would like to make it look like 2-4 people already have the product in their cart.

So I made an adjustment to that existing code, I added `$in_basket = rand(2, 4);` which gives as complete result:

```php
function show_no_of_people_added_in_cart() {
    global $wpdb, $product;
    
    $in_basket = rand(2, 4);
    
    $wc_session_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT session_key FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_sessions" );
    $wc_session_keys = wp_list_pluck( $wc_session_data, 'session_key' );
    
    if ( $wc_session_keys ) {
        foreach ( $wc_session_keys as $key => $_customer_id ) { 
            // if you want to skip current viewer cart item in counts or else can remove belows checking
            if( WC()->session->get_customer_id() == $_customer_id ) continue;
            
            $session_contents = WC()->session->get_session( $_customer_id, array() );
            $cart_contents = maybe_unserialize( $session_contents['cart'] );
            
            if ( $cart_contents ) {
                foreach ( $cart_contents as $cart_key => $item ) {
                    if( $item['product_id'] == $product->get_id() ) {
                        $in_basket += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $in_basket ) 
        echo '<div class="in-basket">' . sprintf( __( 'Hurry! %d people have this in their cart!', 'text-domain' ), $in_basket ) . '</div>';

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_no_of_people_added_in_cart', 11 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_no_of_people_added_in_cart', 21 );
```

**But the problem with is** that at every refresh the number changes. How can I keep that random number for a while? Any advice?

Comment: Store your randon numbers into the session, or seed the random generator with a start value that stays the same for a longer period of time (for example the number of the current day of the year.)

Answer (score 2):

I would use sessions to store the number of people who have the product in their cart.

In the example below, I am gonna keep the same number in the session for 1 minute (60 seconds).

First, enable sessions in Wordpress - at the beginning of `function.php` put this code:

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();

    // create a session 'randinbasket' containing an empty array if it doesnt exist
    if (!isset($_SESSION['randinbasket'])) $_SESSION['randinbasket'] = array();
}
```

Then, create a function which either gets a number from the session or generates a new one:

```
/**
 * Generates a random number, stores it in a session
 * @param integer $minCount - minimal number
 * @param integer $maxCount - maximal number 
 * @param integer $prodId - product ID
 * @param integer $expiresAfter - session expiry in seconds 
 */
function get_random_in_basket($minCount, $maxCount, $prodId, $expiresAfter) {
    $inBasketData = $_SESSION['randinbasket'];
    $prodKey = 'product_' . $prodId;
    $timeNow = time(); // current timestamp
    $randomCount = rand($minCount, $maxCount);

    if (isset($inBasketData[$prodKey])) { // If product data exists in the session
        $inBasketProductData = $inBasketData[$prodKey];

        // If current time is within expiration time
        if ($timeNow <= $inBasketProductData['time'] + $expiresAfter) {
            return $inBasketData[$prodKey]['count'];
        }
    }

    $inBasketData[$prodKey] = array(
        'time' => $timeNow,
        'count' => $randomCount
    );

    $_SESSION['randinbasket'] = $inBasketData;
    return $randomCount;
}
```

Finally, slightly modify your `show_no_of_people_added_in_cart()` function:

```
function show_no_of_people_added_in_cart() {
    global $wpdb, $product;
    
    $in_basket = get_random_in_basket(2, 4, $product->get_id(), 60);

    $wc_session_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT session_key FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_sessions" );
    ...
```

If the code above works for your WP, consider increasing the session expiry time from 60 seconds to 86400 seconds (equals 1 day):

```
$in_basket = get_random_in_basket(2, 4, $product->get_id(), 86400);
```

---

**UPDATE**

There seems to be an error in the code of your function `show_no_of_people_added_in_cart()` which causes Wordpress to not add/substract 1 from the randomly generated number after you add/remove a product to/from your basket.

In short, this line:

```
$cart_contents = maybe_unserialize( $session_contents['cart'] );
```

should store the contents of your basket into a variable, BUT IT STORES NOTHING AT ALL.

To fix this issue we have to replace line above with these 2 lines which actually get the contents of your cart:

```
global $woocommerce;
$cart_contents = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
```

---

Comment: I added the first 2 snippets in functions.php (the theme's functions not child's). The snippets don't break the website or page, but when refreshing the page, the value changes again (sometimes if I refresh 2 times). I need it to display the same value, many hours if possible (24?).

Comment: I fixed an error in my code and updated the answer. Tested on my server with WP, it should work now.

Comment: Thank you! I think there are many people that want this, there are similar plugins for sale but nothing like this snippet here. And it can be improved in a plugin :)

Comment: My answer was a bit rushed, now it keeps the same value, and if anyone ads a product to their cart, the value doesn't change. The end result should be an addition: rand(2,4) + the real value taken from the cart, does it make sense?

Comment: If  your original code worked correctly after adding products into the basket, make sure your `show_no_of_people_added_in_cart()` function's code remained the same as before except for the line number 4 where we replaced `$in_basket = rand(2, 4);` with `$in_basket = get_random_in_basket(2, 4, $product->get_id(), 60);`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't explain well enough, the original code had $in_basket = 0; It worked OK just for the real number of people that have the item in cart. I'm trying to create a sense of urgency, it's used nowadays in many things, for the people to buy faster, or at least buy :)

Comment: I know that :D That's why I asked you if you kept your `show_no_of_people_added_in_cart` code as it was before except for the line number 4 where we replaced `$in_basket = rand(2, 4);` with `$in_basket = get_random_in_basket(2, 4, $product->get_id(), 60);`. I am gonna try make a plugin for that because I need it too, keep checking this thread.

Comment: OK, so I found the problem - there is this line in your code `$cart_contents = maybe_unserialize( $session_contents['cart'] );` that should return the contents of customer's cart, but in reality it returns NOTHING. You have to replace that line with this line: `global $woocommerce; $cart_contents = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();`. After that, it should be working fine.

Comment: I entered the page, it said, 2 people have in cart, I pressed add to cart then it said, 9 people have in cart, still something wrong

Comment: It's working fine on my new test store https://wp.phamtheanh.eu - I have set the session expiry to 15 seconds so you can try yourself. Maybe theres is something wrong with your sessions and you have to delete them all before implementing this snippet. Or you can try simply replacing every `'randinbasket'` with a new session name - for example `'randinbasket2'`. BTW I have the latest versions of both WP and Woocom

Comment: I deleted everything and tried again, tried with randinbasket2, I changed the values in rand also, when I enter the page, from 2 at the beginning.. if I press add to cart it shows 10-12, I open another incognito page from other browser, if I press again it jumps to 20... something is not right

Comment: Any news on this? still making a plugin? I also have the latest woocommerce and wp, but it still doesn't work.